# How to reduce svg size to clipped area?

Tags: svg

Is it possible to reduce the actual size (i.e. width and height) to the clipping? Let's see the svg below for an example:

The underlying "base" image has a size of 272x136 pixels. The clipping result has a size of 17x17 pixels. Now I would like that the resulting svg is resized to 17x17 pixels. Is that even possible?

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
   <rect x="102" y="102" width="17" height="17"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/sprite.png" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" />  
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that takes effect before the content is clipped, resulting in an empty image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the area you want to see with a viewBox and then set the size of the SVG to whatever you want using the outer `<svg>` element's width and height

I've also added width and height attributes to the image element so it works on browsers other than Chrome/Opera.

```html
<svg width="17px" height="17px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="102 102 17 17">
        <defs>
                <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
                        <rect x="102" y="102" width="17" height="17"/>
                </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image xlink:href="https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/sprite.png" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" width="272px" height="136px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome! Conclusion: The solution is the combination of svg-size and viewbox.